# Magento 2.4.2, child theme of Blank - Front end. How do you remove properties in parent Blank theme styles, for example footer border?

Tags: theme, frontend, less, magento2.4.2, vendor

The file I use to override these styles: `app/design/frontend/Vendor/ChildTheme/web/css/source/_module.les`s as per M2 documentation.

I tracked that it applies my modified styles, but then goes and puts the original on top, overriding my customisation.

Simple solution might be setting border: 0; but that's not what I want to achieve here. I need that rule removed.

[image: 2021-05-06-09-13.png]

To track it I added properties **content: "Theme"** and **content: "Vendor"** indicators. As you can see, the one from theme has border rule removed, but it gets overridden by rules from vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.
I was adding it as general theme styling, It should have been app/design/frontend/Vendor/ChildTheme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less

Now if some rule is removed - it stays removed.